# convert PHP into C#

Tags: c#, php

i'm converting php script into c# i have everything instead of this one line

```
$data = array('sms_package' => json_encode(array(array('number' => $to_msisdn, 'message' => $message))), 'from' => $from_msisdn);
```

i was trying with `JavaScriptSerializer` but i'm unable to construct same arrays.

I was even trying with classes:

```
 public class Sms_Package
    {
        public string number;
        public string message;
    }

    public class OToSend
    {
        public Sms_Package sms_package;
        public string from;
    }
```

Any solution how to get this?I need to post that data into php script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries, i found it.

I used `NameValueCollection` with serialized `Dictionary<string,Dictionar<string,string>>`. Now it's passing data correctly :)